# Verilog output port is high impedance (Z) when driven by a sub module

Tags: verilog

I'm writing code for shifting 4-bit using carry flag  for generating  delay using instantiating but when I'm instantiating in top module output of top module `temp1` always remain in high impedance state could you just check and tell me where I am doing wrong? In an test bench I am giving `win=4'b1100` as an data...

The code follows:

```
module iir_model(temp1,win,clk);
    input [3:0] win;
    input clk;
    output reg [3:0] temp1;

    delay_4   a1(temp1,win,clk);
endmodule


module delay_4(data_out,data_in,clk);
    input [3:0] data_in;
    input clk;
    output [3:0] data_out;

    reg [3:0] data_out;
    reg [2:0] counter=4'b000;
    reg [3:0] temp;
    reg carry;

    integer i=0;
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin 
        i=i+1;
        if(i==1)
            temp=data_in;
        if(i>1)
        begin
            if(counter!=4'b100)
            begin
                carry=temp[0];
                temp=temp>>1'b1;
                temp[3]=carry;
                $monitor ($time," clk=%b,  counter=%b ,temp=%b ,carry=%b,data_out=%b",clk, counter,temp,carry,data_out);
                counter=counter+1;
            end
            data_out=(temp==data_in)?temp:4'b0000;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `temp1` in the top level should be a `wire`, not an `reg`, as `reg` is not intended to be driven from an output port of a module.

Try changing to just `output [3:0] temp1;`